# Css makes different results depend on the admin accounts and other users

Tags: web-part, 2013, css

```
<div class="webpartDivBody" style="margin-bottom:-20px;">
<WebPartPages:ScriptEditorWebPart runat="server" .....></WebPartPages:ScriptEditorWebPart>
</div>
```

This code works for admin accounts. And looks terrible cause of the **margin-bottom**.

But for the other normal users, it doesn't work. So it looks fine.

When I remove **margin-bottom:-20px**, for admin accounts it looks fine.

But it looks bad for the other normal users.

So how can I make this style looks same with all user accounts? I just don't want to use margin-bottom. I think the reason is depends on the WebPart. Because other divs without Webpart don't need anything like that. Thank you.

Here is the orginal Webpart:

```
<WebPartPages:ScriptEditorWebPart runat="server" Content="
&lt;table width=&quot;270px&quot; height=&quot;80px&quot; &gt;
&lt;tr&gt;
&lt;td&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml&quot;&gt;&lt;img style=&quot;height:35px;&quot; src=&quot;/SiteAssets/dolar.png&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td style=&quot;font-size:10px;text-float:left&quot; &gt;ABD DOLARI (Alış)&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;IFRAME marginWidth=0 marginHeight=0 src=&quot;http://ahapp/kurlar.aspx?Q=USD&quot; frameBorder=0 width=62 scrolling=no height=13 &gt;&lt;/IFRAME&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml&quot;&gt;&lt;img style=&quot;height:35px;&quot;  src=&quot;/SiteAssets/euro.png&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td style=&quot;font-size:10px;text-float:left&quot;&gt;EURO (Alış)&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;IFRAME marginWidth=0 marginHeight=0 src=&quot;http://ahapp/kurlar.aspx?Q=EUR&quot; frameBorder=0 width=62 scrolling=no height=13&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;/table&gt;" Title="Script Editor" Description="Allows authors to insert HTML snippets or scripts." ChromeType="None" ID="g_9dbf023f_ed28_4cdf_ad7d_e6609120ddfa" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{CBDD0DA1-FFF3-4332-BBB8-7B089CCD1881}" WebPart="true" __designer:IsClosed="false"></WebPartPages:ScriptEditorWebPart>
```

Comment: Are all pages checked in as major versions and approved?

Comment: It's at the home page. And there is no check in option.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="webpartDivBody" style="margin-bottom:-20px;">
```

is nothing SharePoint specific and doesn't care about user roles.
If the resulting web page looks different for two guys, the typical reason is that they are not using the same web browser (type or version), e.g. A uses IE9.xxx,, B uses IE10.xyz and C uses Firefox 21.y. It's quite possible they all see slight or sometimes larger differences, because browser manufacturers unfortunately implemented some details differently (sometimes even simply wrong).

Comment: No, I test at the same browser. I log out one user and login another one.

Comment: Okay, then it can be either different user dependent browser settings, or the HTML generated on the server is different in the relevant places. (For the latter, you might want to save a copy of the page once for each of the two users, put it in a diff viewer, to see where the difference is created, and check in your SharePoint pages later where this section is created, and why it's different for these users.)

Comment: Do you mean the same thing with @Dave Paylor ?

Answer (score 0):

If it looks different for both users when you change the CSS then it is working for both of them.  It sounds like you have something else that only applies to admins which is having an impact.

Comment: What or where should I look for a reason deeply?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing it but easiest way would probably to have a normal user and admin side by side so you can compare using developer tools or firebug or similar.

Comment: There is just typical permission differences. Not anything specific

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IE? Do you have compatibility view turned on as another user but not as admin? If so, it will look differently. Check to make sure that compatibility view is on for all users & admin or turned off for all users & admin. Alternatively, you can force IE to render the pages at its highest version by using an IE meta tag like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: I did that but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the game, but experienced the same thing.  My Style Library folder had unique permissions.  Those with limited permissions such as Restricted Read and View were  not loading the style-sheet.  I asked the client to perform F12 keystroke and use the select element to view a specific div style.  The custom css was not loading for these clients at all  and didn't appear in the right pane.  I upped permissions for auth users and it fixed the issue. I hope it helps somebody.